# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. [Problem using a decrypted DES key]

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, des

I'm working on a set of programs that encrypt data and then decrypt it again (as to create a document that has to be revised by an office).

I'm using DES for the user data and then i encrypt the DES key using the public key of the office, this part does not generate errors, but when I try to decrypt the key and use it the following error appears:  **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded.**

I've searched for this error but since none of the cases I've found are similar to mine, I can't find what's wrong.

Here is the code I use to genereta and encrypt the DES key (the encrypt is done by retrieving the public key from a file):

```java
//create DES key

        KeyGenerator generadorDES = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        generadorDES.init(56);
        SecretKey claveDES = generadorDES.generateKey();


//encrypt data with DES key

        Cipher cifradorDES = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cifradorDES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, claveDES);

        byte[] bufferDatos = datosJson.getBytes();
        byte[] datosCifrados = cifradorDES.doFinal(bufferDatos);


//encrypt DES key

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());  

        KeyFactory keyFactoryRSA = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

        File ficheroClavePublica = new File(args[2] + ".publica"); 
        int tamanoFicheroClavePublica = (int) ficheroClavePublica.length();
        byte[] bufferPub = new byte[tamanoFicheroClavePublica];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(ficheroClavePublica);
        in.read(bufferPub, 0, tamanoFicheroClavePublica);
        in.close();

        X509EncodedKeySpec clavePublicaSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bufferPub);
        PublicKey clavePublicaOficina = keyFactoryRSA.generatePublic(clavePublicaSpec);

        Cipher cifradorRSAOficina = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        cifradorRSAOficina.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clavePublicaOficina);  

        byte[] claveDESCifrada = cifradorRSAOficina.doFinal(claveDES.getEncoded());
```

Then I store it with the rest of the data and when it's the office turn to decrypt this is the code (again, the private key is retrieved by a file):

```java
//decrypt DES key

        File ficheroClavePrivada = new File(args[2] + ".privada"); 
        int tamanoFicheroClavePrivada = (int) ficheroClavePrivada.length();
        byte[] bufferPriv = new byte[tamanoFicheroClavePrivada];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(ficheroClavePrivada);
        in.read(bufferPriv, 0, tamanoFicheroClavePrivada);
        in.close();

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec clavePrivadaSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bufferPriv);
        PrivateKey clavePrivadaOficina = keyFactoryRSA.generatePrivate(clavePrivadaSpec);


        Cipher cifradorRSA = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        cifradorRSA.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, clavePrivadaOficina);

        byte[] claveSecretaB = cifradorRSA.doFinal(claveDESCifrada);

        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactoryDES = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");

        DESKeySpec DESspec = new DESKeySpec(claveSecretaB);
        SecretKey claveSecreta = secretKeyFactoryDES.generateSecret(DESspec);


//decrypt user data

        byte[] datosPeregrinoCifrados = paqueteCred.getContenidoBloque("datosPeregrino");

        Cipher cifradorDES = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cifradorDES.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, claveSecreta);

        byte[] datosPeregrinoDES = cifradorDES.doFinal(datosPeregrinoCifrados);
```

According to the error, the exception is in the last line. I think that's all the relevant code for the execption, and again I'm not sure what could be wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why you are using the outdated DES. The important part is missing! Where is the encryption code with DES?

Comment: @kelalaka totally forgot about that part! I added it now under the `//encrypt data with DES` comment. As for the outdated DES, I'm totally new to Cryptography so I'm using the examples I was given, but if there's a better option please let me know.

Comment: You should use Authenticated Encryption mode with AES, like AES-GCM or ChaCha20-poly1305. With these, you will have Confidentiality, Integrity, and Authentication. I would like to note that your variables are not in English so they are not meaningful for all. Next time better use in English?

Comment: This Might help [you](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-des.html)

Comment: @kelalaka: ChaCha20-Poly1305 only if java 11 up or Bouncy 1.64, neither of which is certain today. Also, you recommend j5 on WinXP??? Paula: I don't see anything wrong in your code (except that DES is insecure and even worse in ECB) and it runs successfully for me. **Check your storage:** make sure it can store and return arbitrary bytes (binary data not chars), and make sure it _does_ return for decryption _exactly_ the same bytes created by the DES-encrypt operation (datosCifrados) -- although whatever you did for the RSA-wrapped key seems to be okay.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 while checking the storage I realized I took the wrong parameter to retrieve the public key in the first part of the code, so later I was trying to decrypt the DES key with a private key that didn't match. I fixed that part and now the code works fine! Thank you!